# Haskell method is too slow

Tags: haskell, optimization

I wrote a function in Haskell which looks like this:

```
maxSumme :: [[Int]] -> Int
maxSumme [] = 0
maxSumme (x:l) = if subSumme x < maxSumme l then maxSumme l else subSumme x

subSumme :: [Int] -> Int
subSumme [] = 0             
subSumme (x:l) = x + subSumme(l)

-- function call
maxSumme [[7,2,4],[5,8,1],[7,9,2]] -- with 25 innerLists
```

I tested it but this method is very slowly. If I call it with a list of 25 innerLists with 3 items it takes up to a minute to calculate the maxSumme. That is not normal isn't it? I must have made ​​a mistake but I can't find it. How can I optimize my method? Is there a faster way to do this?

EDIT: I think found the mistake. I'm convinced that it is the `maxSumme l then maxSumme l`. I loop throught the list to often each time and that takes so long. But actually I have no idea how to avoid that.

Comment: `let` lifting the `maxSumme l` reduces the time complexity from exponential to linear.  CSE is not always ok in lazy languages, but it is in this case.

Comment: I'm new to Haskell. What do you mean with left lifting and CSE? It would be great if I can change it to a linear function

Comment: He means wrapping the code which repeat `subSumme x` in `let ssx = subSumme x in ...` (and replacing `subSumme x` with `ssx`). It's like defining a new variable, in some sort. Also the same goes for `maxSumme l`.

CSE means "common subexpression elimination". If the compiler would have realized that those expressions are the same, it could have done what we just described and opmitized the _hell_ out of the code, but for some reason it didn't (maybe it's not always ok as Philip suggests).

Comment: CSE can lead to more sharing and thus worsen asymptotic space efficency. GHC thus does less CSE than other agressive production quality compilers for this reason, although it could probably do a better job at handling cases like this.

Comment: @Guido I think the problem is not the unshared `subSumme`, but the unshared `maxSumme`. Leaving `subSumme` unshared costs double; leaving `maxSumme` unshared doubles *the number of recursive calls*, which leads to an exponential cost in the length of the list being recursed on.

Comment: @DanielWagner True. Thanks for pointing it out. By the way, compiling with -O2 does eliminate the common subexps.

Comment: GHC 7.6 appears to perform the CSE even on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you've found the problem function.  It's because for each list, you call `subSumme` many, many times.  What you can do instead is map `subSumme` to each list passed to `maxSumme`, then find the maximum of those numbers:

```
maxSumme xs = maximum $ map subSumme xs
```

If you can't use `maximum`, you'll need to figure out how to implement that yourself =P

---

To explain the `$` operator, it means to always run everything to the right before the left.  It makes an expression like

```
f (g (h (i (j (k (l x))))))
```

into

```
f $ g $ h $ i $ j $ k $ l x
```

Be warned, this gets tricky with functions with multiple parameters.  This wont compile

```
map $ (1+) $ replicate 10 1
```

because it's the same as

```
  map ((1+) (replicate 10 1))
= map ((1+) replicate 10 1))
= map (1 + replicate 10 1)
= map (1 + [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
         ^------ Can't add a number to a list!
```

But you could do

```
map (1+) $ replicate 10 1
```

Basically, all it's for is to remove the need for parentheses in a lot of cases.

Comment: Thank you that works great! I know the maximum function but I do not know the $ operator. What is it for?

Comment: @Cilenco: it does almost nothing (in fact `($) = id`!), but is parsed as an operator with low precedence. Read it simply as parens around everything that needs them, both to the left and right. In this case, `maximum (map subSumme xs)`.

Comment: `subSumme` is actually the same as the standard `sum` function from the Prelude, except that the Platform's version is better optimized. So @bheklilr's solution can be further improved to `maxSumme xs = maximum $ map sum xs`.

Comment: @Guido What part of my arguments are wrong?  If there's a problem I would like to fix it.  I mentioned at the beginning of my post that OP figured out _why_ his solution was slow, and gave an alternative solution that is faster.